# Is it safe to delete .targets files?

Tags: c#, xamarin, mono

I am seeing a build error in a Portable Class Library project, complaining that it isn't referencing .NETPortable, version 4.5, profile7. But it is referencing that. Looking around on the web, I saw at least one person saying they fixed this error by deleting a .targets file.

My question is -- are .targets files autogenerated files? I've never touched one, ever. Is it safe to delete all of them?

Comment: **Do not do this unless you know what you're doing** or else you will ruin the install for the various products that you deleted `.targets` for. `.targets` are used in the `MSBuild` process and represent a group of tasks that each do a unit of work to ensure the respective technology can build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As John Douglas hinted at in his comment above, the answer to this is No. That said, in my particular case, a .targets file was the culprit. What I did to find all this out was make a copy of the entire folder tree, delete the .targets files, then restore the ones I needed.

Comment: It would be valuable to include the `Build Error` in your question so there's more context as to why this fixes the issue. Commonly you would never delete a `.targets` file and rather "modify" it if there were a supposed bug or limitation.

Comment: At this point, it's fixed, so I'm not sure I can, other than the above. I can tell you what I was doing. I had a PCL project that I was attempting to port to .netstandard. I had deleted my PCL project and created a new .netstandard project in its place, and was in the process of adding all the dependencies back when I realized it wouldn't work. I therefore reverted in version control. This is when the error arose. That led me here. https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/103437/your-project-is-not-referencing-the-netportable-version-v4-6-profile-profile44-framework-add-a-r

Comment: My error was the same as the one described at the link, but it was .NetPortable, version 4.5 in my case. There were some switches between VS Mac and PC along the way, too, with the error appearing on Mac.